# Shot in the heavens afar

Tags: riddle, wordplay, visual, poetry, letters

> ```
>     A cloak blankets way overhead,
>     Beginning the time for your bed.
>     Remember my comfort and love
>     Inviting the skies up above.
>     Look! You can reach like a kite;
>     Look and not burn from the light!
>     Is this closer to islands at sea,
>     Albeit you need not to row, actually?
>     Now as I dance through a silent
>     Twirling of milk from a giant,
>     The hearts all below settle down
>     With the rhythms that calm every crown.
>     Imagine five spots only white,
>     Nix - as in, nothing - so bright!
>     Know it is a diamond somewhat,
>     Living by my flight (who knew not?).
>     Even so it will not ever soar!
>     Riddle me that, I implore!
> ```

Notice that this riddle does not ask "What am I?". The answer is actually *staring* at you in the face... quite literally... can you find it? There is an obvious part and the less obvious part. The true aim of this riddle is to find the less obvious part ;)

I was thinking of saving this for my 100th puzzle here, but nah... I got a better idea for that. I wonder what I'll do to *start* off.

---

**Hint 1:**

> What numbered post is this of mine? What numbers divide it? Which is unique?

**Hint 2:**

> Can you derive the answer from the letters of the obvious part? Why... not?

**Hint 3:**

> If every different letter had a different corresponding colour, there may be one particular colour that would *startle* you (though this kind of approach to my riddle might prove exhausting).

Comment: Is there anything to this besides one three-word phrase?

Comment: @Deusovi There must be. I mean, I actually have no idea what three-word phrase you are talking about xD

Comment: What? It's very clearly there, and intentional: there's a phrase in the [rot13: svefg yrggre bs rnpu yvar]. I'm asking because I don't want to post an answer if there's more to it, but I can't see anything implying there is any more.

Comment: @Deusovi oh *that*! I thought by "phrase" you meant "idiom" like some sort of common three word phrase. My bad. No, there definitely is more. I will actually have to add there is more than one thing in the poem staring at you in the face. Thanks for your comment, and apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Well done with this one, @user477343!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's beautiful!

> [image: Question, with color]

Note:

> (I tried getting the markdown editor to render the html for this but ended up just doing a screenshot...)

Comment: You did it! Congratulations! I will upvote this in roughly 40 minutes from now (that's when my daily voting limit will be over) and then I'll give you the tick! Well done to you! :D

Comment: Sorry, I took a nap. All good now xD Good job! Upvoted and $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: *My God, it's full of ...*

Answer (score 2):

Could this riddle be describing

> a **star?**

First, the "answer staring in my face":

> The first letters of each line spell out "A BRILLIANT TWINKLER," which is a clue for a star.

And explanations for some of the lines of the riddle itself:

```
 A cloak blankets way overhead,
 Beginning the time for your bed.
```

> The stars can be thought of as a blanket, cloaking the night sky. Also, when the stars come out, it's usually time to go to sleep! (I should remember that for the future...)

```
 Look! You can reach like a kite;
 Look and not burn from the light!
```

> I guess this refers to the fact that you can't physically go to a star (at least, not as of the publishing of this answer), but they are fairly bright.

```
 Now as I dance through a silent
 Twirling of milk from a giant,
```

> This refers to the Milky Way Galaxy, which revolves around a [supermassive black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*).

```
 Imagine five spots only white, 
 Nix - as in, nothing - so bright!
```

> Five stars can form the Big Dipper constellation, though I'm not too sure if that fits with the "nothing so bright" part.

```
 Know it is a diamond somewhat,
 Living by my flight (who knew not?).
```

> Stars are often depicted as diamonds. "Flight" may refer to how sailors in the past used the positions of stars to navigate their way across the ocean or how pre-Civil War slaves escaping the South via the Underground Railroad used the Northern Star (Polaris) as their guide.

Comment: Yeah, you got it right. Some other verses weren't interpreted the way I intended them to be (e.g. the second last one) but yeah. *HOWEVER...* there is more to the puzzle than this. I am not looking for this type of answer, but I am looking for an answer that finds an actual depiction of what the riddle describes inside the riddle. You found the obvious part staring in your face, but not the less obvious part (see my most recent edit of the question) :)

Comment: All right, I'll take a second look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Playing off the hints and PilsNot3's answer, I thought you may be eluding to a specific star (or stars)...

> Epsilon Ursae Majoris

Reasoning:

> Given the 99th post, the unique number I plucked out that divides 99 is 33. The star by name (noted as Alioth) is the 33rd brightest star in the list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_brightest_stars

Also,

> From the clues in the poem, the stars that make up the Big Dipper can appear as a diamond or a kite, depending on one's perspective or imagination. "Five spots only white" would elude to the stars that comprise the diamond as well as Epsilon Ursae Majoris, which is the first star in the tail.

Comment: Unfortunately, (ROT13) gung vf abg gur ahzore bs zl cbfg. Guvf cbfg vf zl yngrfg bar guhf sne, fb nyy lbh unir gb qb vf ybbx ng ubj znal dhrfgvbaf V unir cbfgrq, naq gur ahzore bs gung jvyy or gur ahzore bs guvf irel cbfg.

Comment: The two most important tags in this puzzle are [tag:visual] and [tag:letters], to give you a kickstart in the right direction :)